# Issue with JSTree drag drop

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using JSTree with ASP.net.
The html generated for the tree looks like

```
    <ul>
            <li ID="Manager1"><a href="#">node 1</a></li>
            <li ID="Manager2"><a href="#">node 2</a></li>
            <li ID="Employee1"><a href="#">node 3</a></li>
            <li ID="Employee2"><a href="#">node 4</a></li>
            <li ID="Employee3"><a href="#">node 5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

When I Drag a node and drop on the other the function written for drag_finish is not getting called. 
The dnd plgin is used as below,

```
    tree.jstree({
        ...
         "dnd": {
            "drop_finish": function (data) {
                alert("some message");
            }

            }

        "plugins": [..., "dnd"]

    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is with the html.

Use class="jstree-drop" along with IDs for all the nodes.
It will work.

The other method could be with 
tree.bind("move_node.jstree", function (event, data){
// your code
}