# Drag and Drop events in dnd plugin in jstree are not getting called

Tags: javascript, jstree

We are using jsTree for tree representation of the Files and folders. Files and folders can be moved in and out from other folders.

For this I have enabled the drag and drop plugin. The folders and files can be dragged and dropped but the events which are called on drag and drop are not getting called.

I need these events to fire on drag and drop as I need to update the status of the drag and drop in the backend using Ajax.

Please help

Below is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="source">

$(function() {

        $("#folderTree").jstree( {
        "dnd" : {
            "drop_finish" : function () { 
                alert("DROP"); 
            },
            "drag_check" : function (data) {
                if(data.r.attr("id") == "phtml_1") {
                    return false;
                }
                return { 
                    after : false, 
                    before : false, 
                    inside : true 
                };

                alert("hhh jjj kk ");
            },
            "drag_finish" : function () { 
                alert("DRAG OK"); 
            }
        },

        "plugins" : [ "core", "html_data", "themes", "ui","dnd"],

        "ui" : {
            "initially_select" : [ "phtml_1" ]
        },

        "core" : { "initially_open" : [ "phtml_1" ] },

        "themes" : {
                "theme" : "apple"
        },

        "types" : {
            "valid_children" : [ "root" ],
            "types" : {
                "root" : {
                    "icon" : { 
                        "image" : "../images/drive.png" 
                    },
                    "valid_children" : [ "folder" ],
                    "draggable" : false
                },
                "default" : {
                    "deletable" : false,
                    "renameable" : false
                },

                "folder" : {
                    "valid_children" : [ "file" ],
                    "max_children" : 3
                },
                "file" : {
                    // the following three rules basically do the same
                    "valid_children" : "none",
                    "max_children" : 0,
                    "max_depth" : 0,
                    "icon" : {
                        "image" : "../images/file.png"
                    }
                }

            }
        }



    });
});
```

Am I missing anything or is there anything else I need to do in order for the drag and drop events to get called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to drag nodes inside of the tree you should use [CRRM plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/crrm), not DND. DND is used to drag nodes outside the tree or between the trees.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using CRRM plugin can I drag and drop nodes inside of the tree? I dont want to have any buttons to do these moving of files and folders.

Comment: I this case you need to use them together. Take a look on that demo and code http://www.jstree.com/documentation/dnd#demo2.

Answer (score 6):

Check with this URL [Issue with JSTree drag drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569798/issue-with-jstree-drag-drop)
Use **class="jstree-drop"** along with IDs for all the nodes. It will work.
For example:-
If you use json data

```
"plugins" : [ "core", "json_data", "themes", "ui","dnd"],
{
    {id : "id1",rel : "folder",class:"jstree-drop"},
    data:"New folder2",
    state:"closed"
}
```

if we use html data then add **class="jstree-drop"** to all nodes.
Then "drop_finish" event will works fine, but not drag_check,drag_finish. I tried by adding jstree-drag in css class.

Updated (after one hour on 19th-July-2011):- add **jstree-draggable** css class to all elements drag events also works fine
more information http://www.jstree.com/documentation/dnd

Answer (score 1):

Options `dnd.drag_check`, `dnd.drag_finish`, `dnd.drop_finish` is uses for **foreign objects**. For manage moving inside one tree (or between trees) use `crrm.move.check_move`.