# JStreeGrid Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jstree

I'm using the JSTreeGrid in an ASP.NET application. The implementation of the JSTreeGrid works fine in the application in which it was designed in tested.  However when I moved it over to another application I recieved the following error message below:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

When I initially moved the implementation over I discovered and corrected issues related to the new application forms utilizing Masterpages. The container names were concatenated to the div tags and the scripts were not finding the declared div tag IDs specified in the script.  The application that I moved it from did not use Masterpages.  I feel resonably certain that the error is related.

The error occurs in the _prepare_grid: function in the jstreegrid script when obj.each(function () section of script is run.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use master pages the Client ID of your DOM elements ia manupulated by the server.
This is due to the chace that you will use the same id both in the master page and in your derived page... when calling Jquery function i would guess that you use id selector i.e. `$('#someID').doSomething()` ...

When using master one of the solutions is to use the following selector as an exmaple:

```
$('[id$=myButton]').click(function(){ alert('button clicked'); });
```

This means that Jquery will select the element with an ID attribute that end with 'myButton'.

for more information follow this post.

[How to use JQuery with Master Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382156/using-dragdrop-with-jstree-and-datatables/12435157#12435157)